# Plotting when time series is in rows not columns- using R

Tags: r, plot

Excel allows you to switch rows and columns in its Chart functionality.

I am trying to replicate this in R. My data (shown) below, is showing production for each company in rows. I am unable to figure out how to show the Month-1, Month-2 etc in x-axis, and the series for each company in the same graph. Any help appreciated.

Data:

[image: sample table]

tibble::tribble( ~Company.Name, ~Month-1, ~Month-2, ~Month-3, ~Month-4, "Comp-1", 945.5438986, 1081.417009, 976.7388701, 864.309703, "Comp-2", 16448.87, 13913.19, 12005.28, 10605.32, "Comp-3", 346.9689321, 398.2297592, 549.1282647, 550.4207169, "Comp-4", 748.8806367, 949.463941, 1018.877481, 932.3773791 )

Comment: as.data.frame(t(data))

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data and the code you're working on so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Hi, sorry new to this site and R. Coming from the world of Excel. The data i have is a table that has up to 100 months of production data for over 7,000 companies. As such, I did not think transpose was efficient. The sample data is shown in my original post next to data with a hyper link. Sorry, this comment is not allowing me to paste it again. I need to show the production for each company in one graph. The x-axis is Month-1, Month-2, etc. The Y-axis will be a time series of production for multiple companies.

Comment: tibble::tribble(
        ~Company.Name,    ~Month-1,    ~Month-2,    ~Month-3,    ~Month-4,
             "Comp-1", 945.5438986, 1081.417009, 976.7388701,  864.309703,
             "Comp-2",    16448.87,    13913.19,    12005.28,    10605.32,
             "Comp-3", 346.9689321, 398.2297592, 549.1282647, 550.4207169,
             "Comp-4", 748.8806367,  949.463941, 1018.877481, 932.3773791
        )

Comment: It's much easier to work with code that's in the question, not comments. You can edit the question to put your data & code there

Comment: Thanks, Camille. Apologies for being such a luddite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip the part where you want to transpose, and infer that your purpose for that was solely to help with plotting. The part I'm focusing on here is *"show the Month-1, Month-2 etc in x-axis, and the series for each company in the same graph"*.

This is doable in base graphics, but I highly recommend using `ggplot2` (or `plotly` or similar), due to its ease of dealing with dimensional plots like this. The "grammar of graphics" (which both tend to implement) really prefers data like this be in a "long" format, so part of what I'll do is convert to this format.

First, some data:

```
set.seed(2)
months <- paste0("Month", 1:30)
companies <- paste0("Comp", 1:5)
m <- matrix(abs(rnorm(length(months)*length(companies), sd=1e3)),
            nrow = length(companies))
d <- cbind.data.frame(
  Company = companies,
  m,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
colnames(d)[-1] <- months
str(d)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  31 variables:
#  $ Company: chr  "Comp1" "Comp2" "Comp3" "Comp4" ...
#  $ Month1 : num  896.9 184.8 1587.8 1130.4 80.3
#  $ Month2 : num  132 708 240 1984 139
#  $ Month3 : num  418 982 393 1040 1782
#  $ Month4 : num  2311.1 878.6 35.8 1012.8 432.3
# (truncated)
```

Reshaping can be done with multiple libraries, including base R, here are two techniques:

```
library(data.table)
d2 <- melt(as.data.table(d), id = 1, variable.name = "Month", value.name = "Cost")
d2[,Month := as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", Month)),]
d2
#      Company Month       Cost
#   1:   Comp1     1  896.91455
#   2:   Comp2     1  184.84918
#   3:   Comp3     1 1587.84533
#   4:   Comp4     1 1130.37567
#   5:   Comp5     1   80.25176
#  ---                         
# 146:   Comp1    30  653.67306
# 147:   Comp2    30  657.10598
# 148:   Comp3    30  549.90924
# 149:   Comp4    30  806.72936
# 150:   Comp5    30  997.37972

library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr)
d2 <- tbl_df(d) %>%
  tidyr::gather(Month, Cost, -Company) %>%
  mutate(Month = as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", Month)))
```

I also integerized the `Month`, since it made sense with an ordinal variable. This isn't strictly necessary, the plot would just treat them as discretes.

The plot is anti-climactically simple:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d2, aes(Month, Cost, group=Company)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Company))
```

[image: sample ggplot2 plot]

**Bottom line:** I don't think you need to worry about transposing your *data*: doing so has many complications that can just confuse things. Reshaping is a good thing (in my opinion), but with this kind of data is fast enough that if your data is stored in the wide format, you can re-transform it without too much difficulty. (If you are thinking about putting this in a database, however, I'd strongly recommend you re-think "wide", your db schema will be challenging if you keep it.)